# How can I make my animation be less jerky?

Tags: android, animation

I'm writing a little game as part of a programming assignment. I've got my sprites/images moving the way I want to, except they're very jerky. Here's how I'm loading up the image:

```
//missile and paint are private members of the animation thread
missile = Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.missile));
paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
startTime = new Date().getTime();
```

The `run` method of my thread is like this:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while(running) {
        Canvas canvas = null;

        try {
            canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);

            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                updatePhysics();
                doDraw(canvas);
            }
        } finally {
            if(canvas != null) {
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`updatePhysics` simply performs calculations and stores the value inside a private member of the thread called `projectilePosition`:

```
function updatePhysics() {
    projectilePosition = interceptionCalculationService.positionAtTime((startTime - new Date().getTime()) / 1000);
}
```

Then, in my `doDraw` method I do:

```
private void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

    ...

    //I update the position of the missile
    canvas.drawBitmap(missile, (int) projectilePosition.getDistance() * 2, (int) (getHeight() - (95 + projectilePosition.getHeight())), paint);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

The problem is that the animation is extremely jerky. The missile follows the correct path, but it's not smooth at all. I assume that's because I don't really control the interval when the thread's `run` method is called. How can I make my animation more smooth? I was looking at `TranslateAnimation`, but I can't figure out how to use it.

This is my first time writing a game and doing graphics/animation, so I'm not well aware of the best practices or even the tools. I got this far by looking up numerous tutorials.

Comment: Is your View derived from a View or a SurfaceView?

Comment: It's derived from `SurfaceView`.

Comment: Then I'd guess you are just trying to do too much per frame ... might be worth upping the priority of the background thread ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to stop relying on the system time and to use a variable (that is a private member of the thread) called `currentTime` that gets incremented in either `doDraw` or `updatePhysics`. So `updatePhysics` becomes:

```
function updatePhysics() {
    projectilePosition = interceptionCalculationService.positionAtTime(currentTime);
    currentTime++;
}
```

`currentTime` is initialized to 0 in the constructor of the thread. This made my animation smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the doDraw method is called as fast as the processor can handle and operating system allows, which means it is affected by other processes and also means it is using a ton of processor time. As a fairly simple but not recommended solution add Thread.Sleep(50) in your while loop. Look up how to use timers for animation.

Comment: I think the problem was I was using the system time to calculate the position of my projectile. I'll add an answer here that describes how I did it.